# Generate FOREIGN KEY using Greendao without manual edit

Tags: android-sqlite, greendao, greendao-generator

Is it possible to create FOREIGN KEY in your database, using greendao-generator, without having to manually edit the createTable methon in *Tablename*Dao.

Manual edit is no option for me.
(Using 3.0.0 version of the generator.)

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This is not supported yet. For future updates check the feature request: https://github.com/greenrobot/greenDAO/issues/169